# Python all items in list of lists true

Tags: python

Made a table of True & False, and all I'd like to do is check if they are all True. Used all() successfully before, but for some reason with the below I fail miserably.

```
data = [[False, False, False], 
[False, False, False], 
[True, True, True], 
[True, True, True]]

print(all(data))
>>> True
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You have multiple lists in the structure, and any non-empty list will evaluate to `True`, regardless of it's contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`all` does not check the bools in each sublist. Each of the non-empty lists are all truthy.

To check that *all* the items in *all* sublists are `True`, you should do:

```
all(x for lst in data for x in lst) # -> False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass each sublist to the `all` function within `all` using a generator:

```
print(all(all(i) for i in data))
```

Output:

```
False
```